# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method in method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
var assignresult = (from i in _Objcontext.DistributorProductMappings 
                    where i.ProductId == items.ProductID && i.DistributorId == items.DId && i.UpdatedDate == items.UpdatedDate 
                    select (int.Parse(i.Purchases) + int.Parse(i.StockTakeback)).ToString()
                   ).FirstOrDefault() ?? "0";
```

this statement not working convertions fails

Comment: Fails with what error?

Comment: {"Message":"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method  Int32 Parse(System.String)  method
, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Answer (score 2):

Your linq expression will be translated to expression that Sql understands, in this case `int.Parse` will not have equivalent conversion.

To fix this issue,  use `Convert.ToInt32()`  instead of `int.Parse`

Comment: Why do you think `Convert.ToInt32` is supported? The truth is that there is **no** any conversion method supported from string to other data type.